OPA - How to calculate the input Impedance

I would like to ask if anyone could explain to me how to calculate the Input Impedance of a given circuit, if the OPA used is an Ideal one.
The task is also to create a simplified schematic of this circuit.
I suspect, that the simplified schematic could be FDNR based.
My original approach was to describe the given circuit by Kirchhoff's laws, since the current I1 passes though the components C1 and R1, and current passing trough the R2 resistor is formed by I1+Ic2.
The input impedance it self can be calculated as Z_in = U1/I1
But when I've tried to express U1 or I1 I came to a dead end.
But to be quite honest I am lost right now, please help.

The abbreviation for an operational amplifier is "op-amp" and not OPA.
